# Annotating ManyToMany Fields and return queryset- Django

Tags: python, django

My code looks like this,

```
Class A:
    amount = models.DecimalField();

Class B:
    amount = models.DecimalField();

Class C:
    amount = models.DecimalField();

Class D:
    amount = models.DecimalField();



Class Common(models.Model):
    a = models.ManyTomanyField(A)
    b = models.ManyTomanyField(B)
    c = models.ManyTomanyField(C)
    d = models.ManyTomanyField(D)

commons = Common.objects.values('id').annotate(total_spent=Sum(F('A__amount') + F('B__amount') - F('c__amount') - F('d__amount')).filter(total_spent__lte=0)
```

Expected Common Queryset will be
  queryset = a__amount+b__amount-c__amount-d__amount == 0

Comment: You mean the `SUM(a__amount) + ...`?

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to do. Can you add python code of your attempt to construct the queryset and explain exactly what output you want.

Comment: Yes but any one manytomany field is None we can keep its as 0

Comment: commons = Common.objects.values('id').annotate(total_spent=Sum(F('A__amount') + F('B__amount') - F('c__amount') - F('d__amount'),